# Is there a name for the design pattern used by drupal_alter()?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, drupal

Within Drupal, the drupal_alter() function is used with the following pattern:

1. Your module (foo) produces some type of object, say by providing a foo_get() method.
2. Before returning the object the foo module calls drupal_alter() on it.
3. drupal_alter() calls hooks provided by other modules that alter the object (e.g. bar_foo_alter()) .
4. The altered object is returned.

In Drupal it's used for things like allowing modules to extend html forms created by other modules.  More info on how it works in Drupal here: http://erikwebb.net/blog/drupal-design-patterns/hooks .

Is there a name for this design pattern?  To summarize, the necessary criteria are:

- A module provides a method that produces an object.
- An arbitrary number of other modules may alter the object before it is returned.
- The altering modules only depend on the producing module.
- The producing module does not depend on the altering modules.

Comment: [This](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-the-basic-concept-behind-hooks) will probably be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

"Poor man's dependency injection." (aka the *Ghetto Listener* design pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

Could be something similar to the decorator pattern?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern